# how to submit data to server from Android app when connection is unreliable

Tags: android

I have an Android app that is storing data locally, and a server is set up so that I can backup this data remotely.

My question is what is the best way to ensure that when data is added locally, it also gets through to the server?

I am currently using HttpUrlConnection to POST my JSON encoded data to a RESTful API. But what happens if the server is unavailable (because the Android phone is out of range, for example)? My basic connect timeout is 10s, but if it is out of range for longer than this then the data won't get sent to the server.

Is there a good way to queue my data submissions so that even if I'm out of range for a long while, they will all get submitted properly once the connection is re-established?

Answer (score 0):

A general approach is the following:

- Decouple your flow of saving data locally and sending it to server. Keep the two actions separate.
- Use a Service to periodically send data from your local Android store to the Server. Plan to catch any errors and build in retry logic. The Service code could determine if the connection is there or not and do the sync accordingly.
- Provide a manual action in your app (depends on your design) to begin syncing data to the server or not. Again plan for catching errors and retry logic.
- Provide a settings page that the user (if required) can tweak how frequent he wants the sync between the local and server to happen.